# sys.argv not appearing when passing argument with #

Tags: python, sys

### System:

Linux - Ubuntu
Python: python3

## PASSING ARGUMENT WITH # NOT WORKING

Hey so i have a bug when im passing arguments using the sys package with a # in one of the arguments. it just doesnt appear in the print i do.
code: 
`import sys print(sys.argv)`

IMAGE OF CONSOLE RESPONSE WHEN RUNNING FILE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05tC.jpg

###### RESUME:

Sys not working when passing an argument with a #

Ive searched and i couldnt find a solution, using google to search

Answer (score 0):

it’s not a bug, just put it in quotes
#is a reserved character

so `python3 test.py hello "#0000"`on the console

thanks kelyan#4642